# save and close a workbook with its existing name and reopen it with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have my VBA code below, I would like that my macro saves and closes on mydesktop my activework with its existing name, then I would like that my macro reopens it. When I execute my macro, it saves and closes my activeworkbook with its existing name on my desktop but it does not reopen the excel file. It seems that the part of the code `Workbooks.Open ("\\C:\users\ing\users3\Xavi\Desktop\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name)` does not work in my macro.

If someone know the solution, that would be great.
Many thanks
Xavi

```
Sub openandsaveactiveworkbookandreopenit ()
Dim myactiveworkbook As Workbook
Set myactiveworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="\\xxxyyyy\users\ing\users3\Xavi\Desktop\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name _
 , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Workbooks.Open ("\\xxxyyyy\users\ing\users3\Xavi\Desktop\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name)

 End Sub
```

Comment: When you close that workbook, you end all macros in that workbook, so there is no code executing.

Comment: Actually if the `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook where this code is in, then by using `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` you will automatically end up with the `ActiveWorkbook` beeing the workbook in the **new** location that you specified in `.SaveAs FileName:=`. So there is no need to close and re-open that. • If your code is **not** in the `ActiveWorkbook` but another workbook, then see Ron's answer below. • Note that *"does not work in my macro"* is no useful error description nor an error message. Always tell/describe **what** is going wrong in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can't run this macro from the ActiveWorkbook -- it needs to run from a different workbook.  See `@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns` comment.
- You've declared (good practice) `myactiveworkbook` but you never use it!
- Once you've closed ActiveWorkbook, you can no longer access it's `Name` property because it doesn't exist.  Save that property in a string variable.

Try this variation, with the macro in a workbook that is not the Active Workbook.  It works OK here.

```
Option Explicit

Sub openandsaveactiveworkbookandreopenit()
Dim myactiveworkbook As Workbook
Dim myactiveworkbookname As String

Set myactiveworkbook = ActiveWorkbook

myactiveworkbook.SaveAs Filename:="c:\users\ron\desktop\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name _
 , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

 myactiveworkbookname = myactiveworkbook.Name

myactiveworkbook.Close

Workbooks.Open ("c:\users\ron\Desktop\" & myactiveworkbookname)
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you!! Special thanks to Ron Rosenfeld, your solution works well... I tried it in my code and it works...